# DHCP interface on docker

Tags: docker, docker-network

I need to test a new DHCP server. I'd like to run multiple dockers with a network interface in DHCP mode and bridged on a physical interface on host (DHCP server is external).
Which is the right way? Must i use [pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework)?
Thanks

Comment: https://goldmann.pl/blog/2014/01/30/assigning-ip-addresses-to-docker-containers-via-dhcp/